# Update value from another table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, let's call them `DAILYDATAWH` and `HOLIDAYS`.

Table `DAILYDATAWH`

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT  STATUSIN                STATUSOUT               WORKINGHOUR     LOSTTIME 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-03-25  8:06:23 AM  2020-03-25  8:07:53 AM  00:00:00        00:00:00
```

Table `HOLIDAYS`

```
ID  HOLIDAYDATE   HOLIDAYNAME
----------------------------------------------------------
1   2020-03-25    Bali's Day of Silence and Hindu New Year
```

I want to update and set with this condition `if STATUSIN == HOLIDAYDATE THEN WORKINGHOUR && LOSTTIME = '00:00:00'`

How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
update d
    set workinghour = '00:00:00',
        lasttime = '00:00:00'
    from DAILYDATAWH d join
         HOLIDAYS h
         on h.holidaydate = convert(date, d.statusin);
```

Comment: can you help me again for answer in my new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560266/calculate-total-time-and-update-value-from-another-table-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment107140398_60560266