# Calculate total time and update value from another table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, let's call them `DAILYDATAWH` and `SUMMARYDATA`

Table `DAILYDATAWH`

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT  STATUSIN                STATUSOUT               WORKINGHOUR     LOSTTIME 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21  8:07:53         00:01:30        00:08:14
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-21 08:16:07  2020-01-21 09:51:21         01:35:14        00:11:23
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-21 10:02:44  2020-01-21 11:58:36         01:35:14        
A2   CHLOE   BB         2020-01-21 07:34:27  2020-01-21 11:49:10         03:49:10        00:32:35
A2   CHLOE   BB         2020-01-21 12:21:45  2020-01-21 15:34:21         03:12:36        00:12:25
A2   CHLOE   BB         2020-01-21 15:46:46  2020-01-21 17:19:47         01:33:01        
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-22 08:00:00  2020-01-22 09:00:30         01:00:30        01:00:32
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-22 10:00:02  2020-01-22 10:05:00         00:05:02        00:10:00
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-22 10:15:00  2020-01-22 11:00:00         00:45:00
```

Table `SUMMARYDATA` (The OUTPUT is `TOTALLOSTTIME`)

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT  STATUSIN                STATUSOUT                TOTALLOSTTIME 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         00:03:37             
A2   CHLOE   BB         2020-01-21 07:34:27  2020-01-21 17:19:47         00:45:00               
A1   ARIA   BB          2020-01-22 08:00:00  2020-01-22 11:00:00         01:10:32
```

**`WORKINGHOUR` is a duration between `STATUSIN` and `STATUSOUT`

**`LOSTTIME` is a duration between `STATUSOUT` and `STATUSIN`

and i need to calculate `LOSTTIME` based on same `NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT` and in the same day. Then, Update and set the value into `TOTALLOSTTIME`. And the datatype of `LOSTTIME` is varchar.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: `UPDATE s
 SET TOTALLT = SUM(d.LOSTTIME)
        FROM SUMMARYDATA s JOIN DAILYDATAWH d ON s.NIP=d.NIP AND s.NAME = d.NAME AND s.DEPARTMENT = d.DEPARTMENT` i've been try that but still error and i don't khow how to calculate date based on same day @PeterSmith

Comment: Do you mean you need to insert data into the summarydata table the summed_up losttime from dailydatawh

Comment: i need to update data `TOTALLOSTTIME` because i've been INSERT other columns @GeorgeJoseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Assuming that TOTATLLOSTTIME is varchar field

You can try the following...

```
merge 
  into summarydata a
 using (  select cast(statusin as date) as date_val
                ,NIP
                ,NAME
                ,DEPARTMENT
               ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(losttime as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time
          from dailydatadw b
        group by cast(statusin as date)
                ,NIP
                ,NAME
                ,DEPARTMENT
        )b
    on cast(a.statusin as date)=b.date_val
   and a.nip=b.nip
   and a.name=b.name
   and a.department=b.department
when matched then
  update   
     set TOTALLOSTTIME = sum_lost_time
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but appear error `Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.`

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check if this works out.

Comment: Thank's for helping me it's very helpful:)

Comment: can you help me again in my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631482/count-summary-records-per-month-with-condition-sql