# Count summary records per month with conditional SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, let's call them table `SUMMARYDATA`

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT       STATUSIN           STATUSOUT             TOTALLOSTTIME 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         00:23:15             
A2   CHLOE  BB         2020-01-21 07:34:27  2020-01-21 17:19:47         01:19:19               
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-22 08:00:00  2020-01-22 11:00:00         01:10:00
A2   CHLOE  BB         2020-01-22 08:05:00  2020-01-21 10:30:00         00:20:00
A11  BELLE  CC         2020-01-21 09:06:20  2020-01-21 13:58:31         00:25:10             
A21  ZIYA   CC         2020-01-21 08:34:27  2020-01-21 17:19:47         02:29:39               
A11  BELLE  CC         2020-01-22 07:06:00  2020-01-22 10:30:00         01:11:00
A21  ZIYA   CC         2020-01-22 09:05:00  2020-01-21 11:40:00         00:20:00
```

I need to `COUNT` the records `where sum(TOTALLOSTIME) group by nip,name,department > 02:00:00` in per month and updated to table `REPORTDATA`, this is a sample output that I meant:

```
DEPARTMENT     MONTH    YEAR   RTOTALLOSTTIME 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BB            01      2020           0              
  CC            01      2020           1
```

The datatype column in `TOTALLOSTTIME` is `nvarchar`

And this is what I've tried so far:

```
select  MONTH(STATUSIN), YEAR(STATUSIN),NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(TOTALLOSTTIME as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time
from SUMMARYDATA b group by MONTH(STATUSIN), YEAR(STATUSIN),NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT
```

That's query just show `TOTALLOSTTIME` in every employee and in per month   .

Comment: If you don't need NIP,NAME in your output, why are you taking it in your query?

Comment: because, i want to calculate `TOTALLOSTTIME` in every employee and in per month foremost @Atk

Comment: please check my updated question @Atk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
select x.department
       ,x.month
       ,x.year     
       ,count(case when x.sum_lost_time >'02:00:00' then NAME end) as RTOTALLOSTTIME 
 from (select MONTH(STATUSIN)  as [month]
               ,YEAR(STATUSIN) as [year]
               ,NIP
               ,NAME
               ,DEPARTMENT         
               ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(TOTALLOSTTIME as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time
          from SUMMARYDATA b 
      group by MONTH(STATUSIN)
               ,YEAR(STATUSIN)
               ,NIP
               ,NAME
               ,DEPARTMENT
        )x
group by  x.department
         ,x.month
         ,x.year
```

Comment: Can you help me again to use update statement in that's query?

Comment: You got to put the query i gave in a merge statement and update the values

Comment: i've tried to put it in you're query in merge statement and update values but still error : 'An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.'

Comment: you can help answer in my new question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650648/sql-update-statement-in-conditional-aggregation thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You are mainly just missing a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    DEPARTMENT,
    MONTH(STATUSIN) AS MONTH,
    YEAR(STATUSIN) AS YEAR,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(second, '00:00:00', TOTALLOSTTIME)) AS sum_lost_time_in_sec
FROM SUMMARYDATA
WHERE
    TOTALLOSTIME > '02:00:00'
GROUP BY
    DEPARTMENT,
    MONTH(STATUSIN),
    YEAR(STATUSIN);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, but the output that i meant is to calculate  `sum(TOTALLOSTTIME)` before in every employee, as in my query before : `sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(TOTALLOSTTIME as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time`

Comment: as in my query before how to set `where 'sum_lost_time > '02:00:00''`? because i've been try that but still not working

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, but the output that i meant is to calculate `sum(TOTALLOSTTIME) group by NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT as sum_lost_time` before and then `where sum_lost_time > '02:00:00'`

Answer (score 1):

use conditional `CASE` statement in a `SUM()`

```
select  DEPARTMENT,
        MONTH(STATUSIN), 
        YEAR(STATUSIN),
        SUM (CASE WHEN TOTALLOSTTIME > '02:00:00') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RTOTALLOSTTIME 
from    SUMMARYDATA b 
group by DEPARTMENT, MONTH(STATUSIN), YEAR(STATUSIN)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, but the output that i meant is to calculate `sum(TOTALLOSTTIME) group by NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT as sum_lost_time` before and then `where sum_lost_time > '02:00:00'` then make case statement as you write

Comment: No need for conditional aggregation here; just use a single `WHERE` clause.

Comment: if it is a `where` condition, there will not be any rows with `RTOTALLOSTTIME = 0`

Comment: you can help answer in my new question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650648/sql-update-statement-in-conditional-aggregation  thank you:)