# sql update statement in conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use update statement when there is a conditional aggregation?
because i need to update this query to my table `REPORTDATA`.

my column in table `REPORTDATA` is `DEPARTMENT,MONTHS,YEARS,RTOTALLOSTTIME,RLATECOME,REARLYLEAVE,RST,ROT` as i mentioned in this select query :

is it possible to use update statement in this query?

```
select s.department
           ,s.month
           ,s.year     
           ,count(case when s.sum_lost_time >='02:00:00' then NAME end) as RTOTALLOSTTIME
           ,count(case when s.sum_late >='00:00:01' then NAME end) as RLATECOME  
           ,count(case when s.sum_early >='00:00:01' then NAME end) as REARLYLEAVE 
           ,count(case when s.sum_st <='8' then NAME end) as RST
           ,count(case when s.sum_ot >='1' then NAME end) as ROT
     from (select MONTH(STATUSIN)  as [month]
                   ,YEAR(STATUSIN) as [year]
                   ,NIP
                   ,NAME
                   ,DEPARTMENT         
                   ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(TOTALLT as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time
                   ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(LATECOME as time))),0),108) as sum_late
                   ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(EARLYLEAVE as time))),0),108) as sum_early
                   ,SUM(CAST(STRAIGHTTIME AS FLOAT)) as sum_st
                   ,SUM(CAST(OT AS FLOAT)) as sum_ot
              from SUMMARYDATA b 
          group by MONTH(STATUSIN)
                   ,YEAR(STATUSIN)
                   ,NIP
                   ,NAME
                   ,DEPARTMENT
            )s
    group by  s.department
             ,s.month
             ,s.year
```

this is what i've tried so far,but appear error `'An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement'`  and can't use group by too

```
merge
into REPORTDATA r
using (select MONTH(STATUSIN)  as [month]
               ,YEAR(STATUSIN) as [year],NIP
               ,NAME
               ,DEPARTMENT         
               ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(TOTALLT as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time
               ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(LATECOME as time))),0),108) as sum_late
               ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(EARLYLEAVE as time))),0),108) as sum_early
          from SUMMARYDATA b 
      group by MONTH(STATUSIN)
               ,YEAR(STATUSIN)
               ,NIP
               ,NAME
               ,DEPARTMENT
        )s


   on r.department=s.department
when matched then
  update   
     set DEPARTMENT = s.DEPARTMENT, 
     RLOSTTIME = count(case when s.sum_lost_time >='02:00:00' then NAME end),
     RLATECOME = count(case when s.sum_late >='00:00:01' then NAME end),
     REARLYLEAVE = count(case when s.sum_early >='00:00:01' then NAME end);
  group by  s.department
         ,s.month
         ,s.year
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
update rd
    set rtotallosttime = q.rtotallosttime,
        . . .  -- rest of columns
    from reportdata rd join
         q
         on rd.department = q.department and
            rd.month = q.month and
            rd.year = q.year;
```

That said, I'm surprised you would approach this with `update`.  I would think you would want to insert the rows instead.

Comment: the reason why i want used `update` statement not `insert` statement because 
I used the `update` statement for generate data. if i used `insert` statement, the previous data that have been inserted will `insert` again and there will definitely be multiple data

Comment: and thank you for helping me, i've been try you're query but still not working...

Answer (score 1):

Use `MERGE`:

```
merge
into REPORTDATA r
using ( select s.department as department
           ,s.month as month
           ,s.year as year
           ,count(case when s.sum_lost_time >='02:00:00' then NAME end) as RTOTALLOSTTIME
           ,count(case when s.sum_late >='00:00:01' then NAME end) as RLATECOME  
           ,count(case when s.sum_early >='00:00:01' then NAME end) as REARLYLEAVE 
           ,count(case when s.sum_st <='8' then NAME end) as RST
           ,count(case when s.sum_ot >='1' then NAME end) as ROT
     from (select MONTH(STATUSIN)  as [month]
                   ,YEAR(STATUSIN) as [year]
                   ,NIP
                   ,NAME
                   ,DEPARTMENT         
                   ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(TOTALLT as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time
                   ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(LATECOME as time))),0),108) as sum_late
                   ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(EARLYLEAVE as time))),0),108) as sum_early
                   ,SUM(CAST(STRAIGHTTIME AS FLOAT)) as sum_st
                   ,SUM(CAST(OT AS FLOAT)) as sum_ot
              from SUMMARYDATA b 
          group by MONTH(STATUSIN)
                   ,YEAR(STATUSIN)
                   ,NIP
                   ,NAME
                   ,DEPARTMENT
            )s
    group by  s.department
             ,s.month
             ,s.year   
        )s
   on r.department=s.department
when matched then
  update   
     set r.month = s.month,
     r.year=s.year,
     r.RTOTALLOSTTIME=s.RTOTALLOSTTIME,
     r.RLATECOME=s.RLATECOME,
     r.REARLYLEAVE=s.REARLYLEAVE,
     r.RST=s.RST,
     r.ROT=s.ROT
```

Remember for update there should be common key between `REPORTDATA` table and `Sub query output`.

Comment: i've been try that but still error : 'An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.'

Comment: can you please edit the question and add the query you are trying?

Comment: you should not use aggregate function in update instead use the same in sub query inside `()using`. Check `merge` in my updated answer.

Comment: Also remember you can not use `department` in `update set` while using `Merge` as you are using the same column for matching `on r.department=s.department`.

Comment: thank you so much, it's work but still can't appear anything. the data still not update into table reportdata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209511/discussion-between-dea-ananda-and-naveen-arora).